# Copying from PDF to Visual Studio

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012

The problem is i can't copy code from pdf to visual studio to look the same: ie i got

```
public class ProductDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProductContext> 
{
 protected override void Seed(ProductContext context) 
   { 
GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c)); 
GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p));
   }
```

and then i get just constant wall of text in visual studio:

public class ProductDatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways { protected override void Seed(ProductContext context) { GetCategories().ForEach(c => context.Categories.Add(c)); GetProducts().ForEach(p => context.Products.Add(p)); }

how the hell should i copy that, because even if i copy it to notepad it stays the same as above...

Comment: Which PDF-Viewer are you using?

Comment: It's Adobe Reader XI v.11.0.11.18

Comment: Adobe Reader always includes the format information of the code, so maybe try using an alternative PDF-Viewer

Comment: Press `Ctrl+K, D`...

Answer (score 1):

After pasting the code in Visual Studio, simply mark it and press **Ctrl-K, F** to format the selected code.

Alternatively, you can also press **Ctrl-K, D** to reformat the whole document.